# Qgis 3.4 - How could I add a QDockWidget to Qgis interface using Python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqt5

I was looking for a way to add a panel and I found `QDockWidget` but I don't seem to find the way to add a new panel since examples I've seen use a Qgis tool to create these panels or use `QDockWidget`to show or hide existent panels by their name.

So the question is: How could I add a custom `QDockWidget` as a Qgis Panel with the content I tell it to load?

This is the way I've been able to create it, it can only be appended to the plugin's interface.

[image: Not like this]

I want it to be placed in the Qgis interface like this one:

[image: It Should be like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method `addDockWidget` from the `QgisInterface`:
https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#ad2c81fbbe55bc9609af7a36e56d6857f

When you have your `iface` object, or from `from qgis.utils import iface`, you can do:

```
iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, your_dock_object)
```

to add your dock widget on the right area.

Comment: This helps me position a DockWidget but what about setting a dock_object, how is it done?

Comment: What do you mean with `dock_object`? Do you refer to the `your_dock_object` in my snippet? It's a object from the class `QDockWidget`.

Comment: yes I tried to create one and I did it but it was placed inside the plugin's interface, and I need it inside Qgis' interface, but I'm really struggling to understand this one...

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean, maybe you can update your question with some screenshots. You can have a look to the InaSAFE plugin, it has a dock. Is-it what you want?

Comment: I want a dock appended next to the map area  like shown in the second image, but I can only manage to do one inside the plugin, I am now showing any code because I want a general answer something that would work if written inside the qgis' python IDLE

Comment: It's what InaSAFE is doing http://docs.inasafe.org/en/_images/run_basic_00.png and what I suggested you to use `iface.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, your_dock_object)`. You need to check where you are adding your dock in your plugin window, remove this line and use the snippet I pasted instead.